# React Native Bugsnag error: TypeError Properties can only be defined on Objects [native code] defineProperty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, bugsnag

We have an react-native app with 25k+ users and have gotten over 1000 crashes over the last 3 months reported in bugsnag. The crash typically happens within 1 sec of startup, but sometimes it takes a few seconds. We have not been able to reproduce this in development. It is happening on both ios and android. The only thing we have to go off of is the stacktrace provided by bugsnag:

iOS bugsnag stack trace:

```
TypeError Properties can only be defined on Objects. 
    [native code] defineProperty
    node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/mergeProps.js:54:21 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js:17:17 _get
    node_modules/react-redux/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js:100:11 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js:17:17 _get
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 res
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 _toConsumableArray
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 _defineProperties
    [native code] value
```

Android bugsnag stack trace:

```
TypeError Properties can only be defined on Objects. 
    [native code] defineProperty
    node_modules/react-redux/lib/utils/isPlainObject.js:20:19 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js:17:17 _get
    node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:130:29 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js:17:17 _get
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 _typeof2
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 RCTDeviceEventEmitter
    node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:59 _defineProperties
    [native code] value
```

The stack traces leads me to believe it has something to do with react-redux.
However I don't believe this issue happened before upgrading to RN v 0.62 which leads me to believe it might have something to do with RN 0.62

here are the dependencies in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.16",
    "@fragaria/address-formatter": "^2.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
    "apisauce": "^0.14.3",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.20.0",
    "bugsnag-sourcemaps": "^1.0.4",
    "emotion-theming": "^10.0.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-round": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^2.4.3",
    "react-native-call-detection": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-intercom": "^13.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-notifications": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "~1.1.1",
    "react-native-pie": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-rate": "1.1.10",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-sound-player": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.0.3",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addons": "5.1.11",
    "@storybook/react-native": "5.1.11",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-plugin-context": "^2.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "wd": "^1.11.4"
  }
```

Any clues as to what the issue may be?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm facing the same error and couldn't found anything

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error "TypeError Properties can only be defined on Objects [native code] defineProperty". I solved it by replacing some code using @react-native-firebase/messaging.

you can try replacing the code

```
`
useEffect(() => {
    messaging().getToken().then(token => {
      //some logic code
    });
    return messaging().onTokenRefresh(token => {
      //some logic code
    });
}, []);
`
```

with

```
`
useEffect(() => {
    messaging().getToken().then(token => {
      //some logic code
    }); 
    messaging().onTokenRefresh(token => {
      //some logic code
    });
}, []);
`
```

Comment: I don't think that is my issue. I'm pretty sure I'm implementing `onRefreshToken` correctly